# Mysql auto increment Id does not follow the order when use prepared statements

Tags: mysql, go, prepared-statement

i have a simple code writen in Go to insert in mysql databse, my table structure is:

```
id    PK, AUTO_INCREMENT
name  varchar(100)
email varchar(100), UNIQUE
```

and my go code is:

```
stmt, err := c.mysql.Prepare("INSERT mytable SET name = ?, email = ?")
checkError(err)

res, err := stmt.Exec("My Name", "mail@mail.com")
checkError(err)

lastId, err := res.LastInsertId()
checkError(err)
```

When email is not registered on the bench the insert is made with success.

But when this email registered the bank returns me unique key error , which is correct

The error happens when i insert a record after Obtaining the unique key error , the new insert is made ​​successfully but the bank ID is not in the correct order , eg

```
insert 'My name', 'email1@mail.com' -> id returned 1
insert 'My name', 'email2@mail.com' -> id returned 2
insert 'My name', 'email1@mail.com' -> Unique key error returned
insert 'My name', 'email3@mail.com' -> id returned 4
insert 'My name', 'email1@mail.com' -> Unique key error returned  
insert 'My name', 'email1@mail.com' -> Unique key error returned
insert 'My name', 'email3@mail.com' -> id returned 7
```

Comment: This is correct behaviour. Why are gaps in the sequence an issue?

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation: [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html):

> In all lock modes (0, 1, and 2), if a transaction that generated
>   auto-increment values rolls back, those auto-increment values are
>   “lost”. Once a value is generated for an auto-increment column, it
>   cannot be rolled back, whether or not the “INSERT-like” statement is
>   completed, and whether or not the containing transaction is rolled
>   back. Such lost values are not reused. Thus, there may be gaps in the
>   values stored in an AUTO_INCREMENT column of a table.

It explains why there are gaps in the auto_increment value.
Remember that the purpose of the auto_increment is only to return a value that is guaranteed unique in the column. You will have gaps each time you have failed inserts, each time you delete records then insert new ones...but it shouldn't be a problem.